# Is there a developer licensing program for OSX?

Tags: macos

Microsoft offers a bunch of incentives for developers (like MSDN) and startups (like BizSpark) to get them to develop software for the Microsoft platform with less investment. MSDN for example allows me to test my software on every version of Windows in existence without buying a full license to that version. BizSpark is even better, giving all the software essentially for free, as long as it's used for the startup's business purposes.

Does Apple offer something similar?

P.S. So far the only legal way of testing our software on OSX that I found is to buy a Mac Mini, which costs almost as much as MSDN and doesn't come with a tenth of the benefits (as far as software development is concerned).

Comment: If your product can't pay for itself then don't develop it. There is plenty of hastily ported Windows software out there already.

Comment: And if I don't know if it will pay for itself yet?...

Comment: Looking for cheap hardware? Get a used mac mini from ebay. The G4's with Leopard should work fine for a lot of mac dev things.

Comment: You could consider finding someone you might know with a mac or going to an apple store and explain your thinking of porting a program to mac and asking for a little play with XCode. This might give you a an approximate idea of how easy or feasible it would be to port your app and help you judge whether would be worth investing in some cheaper hardware or if its going to take far to much to get it working within the available frameworks. Its not going to give you the complete picture but it will maybe aid your judgement.

Comment: Based purely on the nature of the question and your fondness for C#, I would go ahead and bet that it's not going to be worth the expense or the effort for you.

Comment: This is not fair to include mac hardware for comparing fees with MSDN.

Comment: from your P.S. it sounds like you already have a Mac product which you have YET to run on a Mac (legally, as you put it). I have to agree with NSD and warn you that the chances of the Mac community embracing your product are little to none... and, doesn't it seem a bit odd in and of itself that microsoft developers require "incentives"?

Comment: Thanks everyone, both positive and negative comments were helpful in getting me into the right mindset. @kent: no, there is no product yet, only some "tests" for various GUI toolkits. @mouviciel: respectfully disagree, since other products can be legally run in VirtualBox on the hardware I already have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The closest thing I know of is the Mac Developer Program which gives you access to various resources but specific to your question you gives you access to software currently in development for compatibility testing etc as well as other compatibility testing tools. You still need a mac to make use of many of the benefits but if you are a member you do get a hardware discount. I'm not aware of any service that is as extensive as MSDN and as the features mentioned are only available to ADC Select or ADC Premier accounts. I can't give you exact details of everything an overview can be found at http://developer.apple.com/products/mac/program/

You can access many resources with a free ADC account though non of the features anywhere near what you are talking about are in the free account.

Edit: I forgot to add that there is a "compatibility labs" feature that allows you to test your software against different setups and os version etc. It says on the site: 
"The Compatibility Labs feature a wide range of Macintosh configurations, allowing you to test on a multitude of Apple technologies with various versions of Mac OS X software, including Intel-based or PowerPC Macs, Xserve, iPhone, iPod and much more."

Comment: There are different membership levels in this program. With the non-free ones, you can get early versions of system updates and upgrades.

Comment: Yeah I should maybe make it clearer, I have a free one but I am aware that these features are only available on the paid accounts hence why I say I cannot give exact details on those.

Answer (score 2):

With Microsoft, you can get their "Visual Studio  Pro With MSDN Pro" subscription, which is currently about $800 a year. That provides operating system installs (which you have to unlock online, ten at a time), technical documentation, and the Visual Studio development system. I think you might get a few developer tech support incidents with that.

With Apple, you can join the ADC Online program for free; that gives you complete technical documentation and the XCode development system. Then you can buy Snow Leopard for $29 and do unlimited installs because there's no key - or if you buy a new Mac, you get it for free. You can don't get any developer tech support incidents, but you can join a boatload of free Apple-sponsored email lists, online developer forums, and so on which their internal engineers are pretty active.

In both cases, you still need hardware. For Mac development, that's $600 for a Mac Mini which includes the development system and unlimited OS installs. For Windows development, that's $800 for the OS installs and development system, plus whatever else you spend on hardware.

I pay the $800 a year for the MSDN/Visual Studio subscription. I also pay $499 a year for an Apple Select membership, which provides extra goodies like a discount on Apple hardware, beta versions of the OS, and developer tech support incidents.

MSDN was a pretty good deal a number of years ago, when they bundled Office with it. Now that it's mostly Visual Studio plus Windows installs, not so good. These days, I think Apple's offerings provide much more value for the money - especially the free ones - but YMMV.

Comment: you don't even need to join ADC online program: XCode ships with *every* OSX installation.

Comment: You cannot legally "do unlimited installs" with a $29 Snow Leopard disc. Read the licensing agreement.

Comment: You can get a 5 license disc for $45.49 for legal multiple installs.

Comment: @NSD: You can if you do them all on the same Mac. There are good reasons for Mac developers to do this on occasion.

Answer (score 0):

OS X ships with all of the dev tools on the install disk.  An [ADC select membership](http://developer.apple.com/products/overview/select.html) ($500) is cheaper than Visual Studio or an MSDN subscription, as far as I can tell.

I don't know of any BizSpark-like program on the Apple side.

Comment: AAPL doesn't need a BizSpark-like program, they have one: it's called the "App Store" (aka iTunes).

Comment: BizSpark is not just about helping you distribute your product. It also offers you all the development tools and operating system licenses for a fee of $100 that you pay three years after signing up - which is an exceptional deal.